# Needed Vue JS knowledge for Shopware development?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

I would like to customize Shopware 6 templates and write extensions for the backend. How good do my Vue JS skills need to be for this? Are the basics including Vuex, Vue Router enough? Or do I also need to master advanced techniques like the Composition API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither knowledge of Vuex nor advanced techniques are required to get started. If you [get the basics down](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html) you should be good to go.